# A contradiction about no. of elements of order $p$ in $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Then the number of element of order $p$ in $G$ is a multiple if $\phi(p)$. So if $p$ is a prime number, the number of elements of order $p$ in $G$ is $k(p-1)$ for some integer $k$.
But according to [this article](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/McKay59.pdf) the number of elements of order $p$ is $pk-1$ for some integer $k$ when $p$ is a prime. But this two results are different.

Comment: Yes, they are different, but as Zach (+1) is explaining to you, they don't contradict each other. The first non-trivial example I could think is with the group $G=C_7\rtimes C_3$. Consider $p=3$. In the group $G$ there are $14$ elements of order three. Here $14=7(3-1)$ and $14=5\cdot3-1$, so it is both of the form $k(p-1)$ and of the form $pm-1$.

Comment: Viewed in yet another way. You cannot rule out the possibility of a group with exactly four elements of order two with the former result. To that end you need the latter result which states that any finite group must have an odd number of elements of order two.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the results are different.

1. The number of elements of order $p$ is a multiple of $p-1$. You said this. (Do you know how to prove it? Consider the set of $p$ element subgroups of $G$...).
2. The number of elements of order $p$ is one less than a multiple of $p$. This is proved in the article that you linked to.

But there is no contradiction here: both results are true.

The number of elements of order $p$ is $k(p-1)$ for some $k$, according to (1), and also $k(p-1) \cong -1 \pmod{p}$ according to (2). Therefore $k \cong 1 \pmod{p}$.

Please note: we can write the number of order $p$ elements as $k(p-1)$ for some $k$. And also we can write the same number of order $p$ elements are $kp-1$ for *a different value* of $k$. It is **not** the same $k$. So perhaps your confusion is because you used the same letter $k$ to stand for two different quantities.

Instead you should say:

1. The number of order $p$ elements is $k(p-1)$ for some $k$.
2. The number of order $p$ elements is $mp-1$ for some $m$.

We have $k(p-1) = mp-1$. So $k(p-1) \cong -1 \pmod{p}$. Therefore $k \cong 1 \pmod{p}$. And $mp-1 \cong 0 \pmod{p-1}$. So $m \cong 1 \pmod{p-1}$.

For example in $G = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, there are $p-1$ elements of order $p$, and $k=1$, $m=1$. In $G = (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$, there are $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$ (all elements except the identity), and $k=p+1$, $m=p$. In $G = (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^e$ there are $p^e-1$ elements of order $p$, and $k=(p^e-1)/(p-1) = p^{e-1}+p^{e-2}+\dotsb+p+1$, $m=p^{e-1}$.

Comment: $k(p-1) \cong -1 \pmod{p}$...why this holds!!

Comment: @user438576 It is edited to clarify now. Your problem is that you used the same letter $k$ for two things. Don't do that.

Comment: So If $N$=No. of elementsts of order $p$ in $G$ then by $(1)$, $N=k(p-1)$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z$ and by $(2)$ ,$k=pt+1$ for some $t\in \mathbb Z$ i.e. $N=(pt+1)(p-1)$.... so the number of elements of order $p$ in $G$ is a multiple of $\phi(p)$ but only multiples of the format $(pt+1)(p-1)$ ...Is it the case?

Comment: Yes. ... By the way I am not claiming that every $(pt+1)(p-1)$ does occur...